# Not able to create a Campaign Member using Process Builder

Tags: process-builder, datetime, campaign-member, create-records

i am creating record 'Campaign member' and want show in related list under Lead Object,

here i have criteria like CreatedDate = NOW() AND Description = abc
based on above mention criteria Process builder's Action will fire and create a 'Campaign member' as we want in place

I am not sure but why **Formula NOW() is not working Process builder in this case**

Please see below screenshot :
[image]

Comment: You can also try when created. You don't need to compare it with Now().

Comment: @Tushar Did not get you. can you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create Process builder you get option to Select when this process builder will run.
[image]

Here the select the first option then you don't need to compare it with `Now()` it will only work when a record is created.

Comment: Yes, that's right but i am also set Description field as in my criteria `if Lead.Description = abc`

Comment: @HSdev you can leave that for now  as it is.

Comment: but it is in my requirement. How can i leave it :) lemme tell you what is my actual criteria, i have a Field `AdGroupId__c` and that is checking field So, basically i can not change my process builder with Campaign from Lead. (This PB was build for Lead) :)

Comment: @HSdev leave it means means you can leave this filter in original place this will not give you any error.

Comment: Ohh got it got it...sorry for late, is this formula (NOW()) is possible as i placed for createddate ?

Comment: @HSdev I don't think that's very reliable. Just use "Only when a record is created." I don't think there's any guarantee that NOW() will return the exact same second as Created Date.